# AutoIT script runs again after execution without another call

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I am automating a Selenium WebDriver test along with chrome, and have an AutoIT script that I call in order to bypass the login of the website.

I call the script with the following code:

```
        try {
                Reporter.log("Running AutoIT log-in script");
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\aaa\\Script\\Auth.exe");
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                driver.close();
                Reporter.log("AutoIT script not found or can't be launched.");
            }
```

> The execution flow is:

1- Chrome launches

2- Script is executed (log in successful)

3- Test runs

4- **Script is executed again**

5- Chrome closes

6- Result; test failed.

I tried adding something like:

```
$g_szVersion = "Login v2.0"
If WinExists($g_szVersion) Then Exit
AutoItWinSetTitle($g_szVersion)
```

In order to make it run once, but since it runs after the script has finished, there's no point to track a duplicated execution like this.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding another method that kills the AutoIt script after your test is ran:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\aaa\\Script\\Auth.exe").destroy();
```